# Coloured table cells not showing

Tags: tables, color, adjustbox

In the following table, the colors are not showing:

```
\documentclass[
11pt,english, onehalfspacing, nolistspacing, liststotoc, headsepline, oneside, chapterinoneline, reqno, a4paper, toctotoc, table]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, natbib=true, autocite=inline, uniquename=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage[font=large,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

%
\usepackage{amsthm, amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, exscale, latexsym, float, eucal, mathtools, adjustbox, textcomp, mathpazo, lipsum, rotating, pdflscape, subcaption, booktabs, makecell, flafter, xpatch, wrapfig, tikz, minted, arydshln, blkarray, tabularx, array}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\begin{adjustbox}{width=.85\textwidth}
\begin{threeparttable}
\setlength\tabcolsep{.1cm}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\caption{Agreement}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{11}{c}}
\toprule\toprule
& I & II & III & IV & V  & VI & VII & VIII & IX & X & XI \\ \midrule

AffinityPropagation & - & \cellcolor{red!25} & & & & & & \\
 
Agglomerative &  \cellcolor{red!25} & - & & \cellcolor{red!25} & & & & \\

BIRCH &  & & - & & & & & \\

CLIQUE & \cellcolor{green!25} & \cellcolor{red!25} &  & - & \cellcolor{red!25} \cellcolor{green!25} & \cellcolor{green!25} & \cellcolor{green!25} & \cellcolor{red!25} & \cellcolor{red!25} &  \cellcolor{green!25} & \cellcolor{green!25} \\

DBSCAN & \cellcolor{green!25} & & & & - & & &  \\

GaussianMixture  & \cellcolor{green!25} & \cellcolor{red!25} & &  &  & - & &  \\ 

$K$-means & \cellcolor{green!25} & \cellcolor{red!25} &  & &  &  & - &  \\

$K$-medoids & \cellcolor{green!25} & \cellcolor{red!25} & &  & & & & - \\

MeanShift & \cellcolor{red!25} & \cellcolor{green!25} & & & & & & & - & &  \\

OPTICS & \cellcolor{green!25} & \cellcolor{red!25} & & & & & & & & - &  \\

Spectral & \cellcolor{green!25} & \cellcolor{red!25} & & & & &  &  &  &  & - \\
\bottomrule\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
```

I am also wondering whether I need all those environments: `table`, `tabular`, `adjustbox`, `threeparttable`

Comment: only scale tables as a last resort, and even then avoid it, so would be good to lose  `\begin{adjustbox}{width=.85\textwidth}` also `threepartable` is a system for adding table notes you are not using so you do not seem to need that.

Comment: In general it helps if you provide an example _document_ that shows the problem so we don't have to guess how to define all the commands used. I would guess colortbl, adjustbox, booktabs, xcolor and tabularx packages are needed here?

Comment: you added some more code but it still doesn't allow anyone to see the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you employ a `tabularx` environment, make the 11 data columns have equal widths, and set the overall width of the `tabularx` environment to `\textwidth`

If you believe that the colored rectangles must be separated by whitespace, while still making the 11 data columns equally wide, I suggest you employ a `tabular*` environment. See the second table below for an implementation of this idea.

I wouldn't set the widths of the `tabularx` or `tabular*` environments to anything much less than `1\textwidth` *unless* your document margins are quite narrow (which is a piece of information you haven't provided so far.) At any rate, do set the intended overall width of the `tabularx` or `tabular*` environment directly instead of via an `adjustbox` kludge. Using that kludge will result in wildly inconsistent font sizes across tables...

Oh, and please don't double the `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` directives -- unless you want to give your table a deliberately amateurish, and even vulgar, "look".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % load the 'colortbl' package automatically
\newcommand\crd{\cellcolor{red!25}}
\newcommand\cgr{\cellcolor{green!25}}

\usepackage{booktabs} % \toprule, \cmidrule, \bottomrule, \addlinespace macros

\usepackage{tabularx} % for tabularx environment
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of X col. type

\usepackage{array} % for 'w' column type
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth{\mylen}{VIII} % measure usable width of the 'w'-type columns

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \setlength\tabcolsep{1pt} % default: 6pt
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
    \caption{\texttt{tabularx}-based solution\strut}
    \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{@{} l @{\quad} *{11}{C} }
    \toprule
    & I & II & III & IV & V  & VI & VII & VIII & IX & X & XI \\ 
    \cmidrule{2-12}
    Affinity Propagation & -- & \crd \\
    Agglomerative     &  \crd & -- & & \crd \\
    BIRCH             & & & --  \\
    CLIQUE            & \cgr & \crd & & -- & \crd & \cgr & \cgr & \crd & \crd & \cgr & \cgr \\
    DBSCAN            & \cgr & & & & --  \\
    Gaussian Mixture  & \cgr & \crd & & & & --  \\ 
    $K$-means         & \cgr & \crd & & & & & --  \\
    $K$-medoids       & \cgr & \crd & & & & & & --  \\
    Mean Shift        & \crd & \cgr & & & & & & & --  \\
    OPTICS            & \cgr & \crd & & & & & & & & --  \\
    Spectral          & \cgr & \crd & & & & & & & & & --  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
    
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\caption{\texttt{tabular*}-based solution\strut}
\begin{tabular*}{1\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{11}{wc{\mylen}} }
\toprule
& I & II & III & IV & V  & VI & VII & VIII & IX & X & XI \\ 
\cmidrule{2-12}
Affinity Propagation & -- & \crd \\ \addlinespace[3pt]
Agglomerative     &  \crd & -- & & \crd \\ \addlinespace[3pt]
BIRCH             & & & --  \\ \addlinespace[3pt]
CLIQUE            & \cgr & \crd & & -- & \crd & \cgr & \cgr & \crd & \crd & \cgr & \cgr \\ \addlinespace[3pt]
DBSCAN            & \cgr & & & & --  \\ \addlinespace[3pt]
Gaussian Mixture  & \cgr & \crd & & & & --  \\ \addlinespace[3pt] 
$K$-means         & \cgr & \crd & & & & & --  \\ \addlinespace[3pt]
$K$-medoids       & \cgr & \crd & & & & & & --  \\ \addlinespace[3pt]
Mean Shift        & \crd & \cgr & & & & & & & --  \\ \addlinespace[3pt]
OPTICS            & \cgr & \crd & & & & & & & & --  \\ \addlinespace[3pt]
Spectral          & \cgr & \crd & & & & & & & & & --  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Beautiful solution! The issue is an option clash with xcolor

Comment: Solved the option clash by: \documentclass[table]{report} \usepackage{xcolor}

Comment: PS. What does \strut do?

Comment: @Sean_TBI_Research - It adds a bit of vertical separation between the caption and the table.